# A detail picture or table showing what the symbols mean in the display in Age of Empires 2

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

The question is about AoE2: the age of kings and the conquerors expansion (I think it's same for both). I am asking about these symbols:

[image] [image]

For example, the knife and armour symbols. I know the general information that they represent things like attack and melee/pierce armour, but is there a picture or a table that shows everything clearly and in detail? Like what does the 12+4 mean in the knife symbol, and how is it different from 16? Some units also have a red circle symbol (I think it's for ranged units). What do the numbers on that symbol mean?

Also, in the scenario editor I think they show the stats for these units a bit differently. I would like to know how the stats are shown in the scenario editor as well, but my main question is the meaning of all the symbols and numbers in the display in the main game.

Comment: In all cases with a + sign, the number on the left is the base value and the value on the right is the result after upgrades. The knife is for attack (though the type of attack is unfortunately not specified). The suit of armor is literally that... The left side is melee armor (think hand-to-hand combat) and the right side is pierce armor (e.g. Arrows). For ranged units the red target gives the range.

Comment: What values are modified by certain techs is described very briefly in the tech tree, but the truth is there are actually *many* armor classes in this game and technical details in play, and you pick them up over time as you play more seriously. If you want to experiment you can download the Genie editor. If you want easy explanations for beginners check of the videos on YouTube by SpiritOfTheLaw

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Why not turn that into an answer?

Comment: Is this the Genie editor? (http://aok.heavengames.com/blacksmith/showfile.php?fileid=11002) I can'r see a download link, do I have to register on the forum to download it?

Comment: @Joachim feel free to convert it to one if you really wish. I generally don't post answers on SE sites because I'm not a fan of how rep works.

Answer (score 1):

> Like what does the 12+4 mean in the knife symbol, and how is it different from 16?

It is the same damage. 12+4 is simply added together and the total output is 16. The number right to the + is comming from unit upgrades.

> Some units also have a red circle symbol (I think it's for ranged units). What do the numbers on that symbol mean?

The  number next to the circle stands for the units range. Either take the number as it is and compare it to other ranged units to get a feeling for how much is what. It's been a while but I think it represents the tiles, that you can also see whenever you open the editor.

> Also, in the scenario editor I think they show the stats for these units a bit differently [...]

The difference might be because of the huge amount of different civilizations, that each have their own bonuses. Or the units are from the campaign. I wouldn't pay that much attention to that.

I think your confusion comes from the hidden bonuses. If you checkout the damage stats on a Pikeman, you ll see that it does very little damage. But if you see it hitting cavalery, it does huge amounts of damage. The reason for that is there is a fixed value added to the Pikemans damge, whenever it hits a cavalery unit. So the damage would be something like 3 + 20 against cavalery and 3 against the rest. Another good example is the Ram. You ll see that it only does 2 damage. But when you see it hitting a building, it actually gainst +200. There are many hidden bonuses like that. They are done this way to have you finding out the effective counters by playing.

Please don't pin me on the exact numbers, but this is the way the system works. If you want a fun way to get into the AoE2 mechanics, you might like the youtube channel called "SpiritOfTheLaw". He goes very in depth into the mechanics in a very fun way.

Comment: So the display doesn't show any such advantages and we are supposed to learn them by playing? Are unit specific advantages (eg pikeman vs cavalry, ram vs buildings etc) also available in an all-tech game, or are they reduced or not available?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by all tech game. Does it mean that you don't need to research anything? In that case, yes.

Comment: @user13267 If you don't want to spend a long time experimenting to find out things like that camels are ships and take extra damage from arrows (no joke), I recommend checking out https://aoe2stats.net/. Click the row in the table corresponding to a unit to get detailed information about all its hidden bonuses and penalties.